# What statement can I use in Rails 3 to render HTML from a small static file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a file in:

```
RAILS_ROOT/public/system/pages
```

It is a snippet of HTML. I would like to render it, along with other things, in one of my views.

But it seems like when I try to do a render from a view, Rails is always looking for a partial. But it doesn't pick up the file even when I name it with a leading underscore. How can I read and display this HTML snippet within a view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried with

```
<%= render :file => 'your/path/', :layout => false %>
```

inside the erb?

Comment: Seems in Rails 3.2.6 I won't need `layout:false` anymore